# C++ double free caused by returning a static_cast<Base> pointer

Tags: c++

I have a factory class that looks like

```
class Base;
class Derived;

class Factory {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Derived>> m_vector;

    std::shared_ptr<Base> create() {
        std::shared_ptr<Derived> p = std::make_shared<Derived>();
        m_vector.push_back(p);
        return static_cast<std::shared_ptr<Base>>(p.get());
    }
};


class Foo {
    void doStuff() {
        std::shared_ptr<Base> m_p = m_factory->create();
        // ....
        m_p = m_factory->create(); // here the code crashed for double free
};
```

where m_vector is a member of the Factory. I had a crash for 'double free' when the returned pointer Changing the create function to

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> Factory::create() {
    std::shared_ptr<Derived> p = std::make_shared<Derived>();
    m_vector.push_back(p);
    return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Base>(p);
}
```

fixed the problem. I understand that the dynamic_pointer_cast creates a pointer that shares the reference count with p, and so a later deletion of the returned base pointer will not lead to a release of the resource as long as p is still contained in the vector.
However, I still don't understand why the code crashed when the pointer stored in m_p was overwritten. At this point, the reference count should go to 0, and it would free the resource (as the reference count isn't shared with the pointer in the vector of the factory). So I would expect this to cause problems when the code would at some point reference the pointer p held by the factory. However, it appears the resource gets freed a second time already. So the first time must be when the stack of the create function unwinds.
Why is that?

Example;

```
#include "memory"
#include "iostream"

struct Foo {

};

struct FooTwo : public Foo {

};

struct Bar {
    std::shared_ptr<FooTwo> m = std::make_shared<FooTwo>();
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> getFoo()
    {
        std::shared_ptr<FooTwo> p = std::make_shared<FooTwo>();
        // std::shared_ptr<FooTwo> p = std::shared_ptr<FooTwo>(new FooTwo());
        m = p;
        return std::shared_ptr<Foo>(p.get());
    }
};

int main()
{
    Bar b;
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> d = b.getFoo();
    std::cout << "Here 1" << std::endl;
    d = nullptr;
    std::cout << "Here 2" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not very familiar with C++, but doesn't `p` get destroyed at the end of `create()`? It seems like you created two `shared_ptr`s with separate reference counts.

Comment: Besides your question, I think `std::static_pointer_cast` would be more appropriate for this case since it is upcasting(Assuming `Base` is superclass of `Derived`).

Comment: but p gets copied into the vector, so its reference count increases by 1, and so, it being destroyed at the end shouldnt release the resource if I understand these things correctly. But agree, initially there are to shared pointers with separate reference counts (which is bad, but I dont understand how this leads to the double free here)

Comment: I agree that It is weird to get double-free error on that line unless `m_vector` erased the element before that line.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/aJp-4z static_cast version dont even compile. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: `std::make_shared` is a function, not a type. You need to change `std::vector<std::make_shared<Derived>> m_vector;` to `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Derived>> m_vector;` instead. And use `static_pointer_cast` instead of `static_cast`

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the line

```
return static_cast<Base>(p.get())
```

won't compile.

1. You cast to value type and not pointer type.
2. The ending semiclon is missing.

**When you post a question, ensure that you write code that compile.** You should provide a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Your code is more or less equivalent to that:

```
std::shared_ptr<Derived> p = std::make_shared<Derived>();
auto *raw_pointer = p.get();
auto *base = static_cast<Base *>(raw_pointer);
std::shared_ptr<Base> ret_value(base);
```

Thus you have 2 distinct `std::shared_ptr` create from a single pointer. Each one, will have a count of one.

Guess what! When the first `shared_ptr` goes out of scope (exit of function), the object is deleted. Then the other pointer is moved into `m_p`.

> At that point, the original object is already destroyed so `doStuff` use an already deleted object which is undefined behavior.

The when `doStuff` is completed, `m_p` also goes out of scope and try to delete the object a second time.

You should **never** create a `shared_ptr` by calling `get` on another `shared_ptr`.

You should call `get` method only when you really need a raw pointer. And when you do so, you should ensure that:

- You won't use the raw pointer after the source `shared_ptr` goes out of scope to ensure you won't use the object once it got deleted.
- You won't delete that pointer manually.
- You won't create another `shared_ptr` based on that raw pointer.

**Update**

If you want to see the count, there is a function `use_count` that could be used for debugging purpose. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/use_count.

Comment: Given that we don't know how `m_vector` is declared, I have not taken that into account as the code is bugged anyway.

Comment: I added some class definition. the vector is a member of the Factory, so when I push the shared pointer to the vector, the object it points to shouldnt get deleted when we exit the function, should it?

Comment: While the exact result depend (when it crash) on the exact code, the fact that you create 2 shared_ptr to the same pointer but unrelated count, it mean that at some point, one of those will get its counter to 0 and delete the object. The other one will also get its counter to 0 at some point and will then delete the same pointer again. And you might also have problem between both events as you might use a deleted object from the shared_ptr that still exist.

Comment: If you do not understand what is happening, then use a debugger and follow the code step by step. It should be very easy to understand what is happening.

Comment: this is understood. but it doesnt explain the double free error as the app already crashes on the first destructor call.

Answer (score 0):

This is my understanding of what happened. The crash appears to result from the memory allocation of make_shared, which on my compiler makes a single call to malloc and allocates the space for the control block and the resource in a single block, with the control block first, then the structure. Taking the raw pointer and creating a new shared pointer creates a shared pointer that points to that resources and to a different control block. When that pointer's reference count reaches 0, it requests freeing up the resource as well as its own control block, however, the pointer to the resource does not point to the beginning of the memory allocation (which begins with the control block of the first shared pointer) and so malloc throws.
Replacing make shared with a regular creation of a shared pointer would make two calls to malloc and allocate a separate block for the control block and for the structure, so the later deletion will not throw a double free (but the first pointer would then point to a corrupt resource)

Comment: Using new, you will also have a double deletion at some point if you don't get problem with corrupt resource first.